# back up for a moment

Tags: phrases

My question is what "back up" means in the following context.

"I want to back up for a moment first."
This is a part of the opening remarks said Mark Zuckerberg during the conference call, that remarks followed the QA sessions.

Does it mean "I want to talk about a bit something else before proceeding with the QA sessions?"

Comment: It probably means "I want to talk about something earlier in the logical development of this topic".

Comment: Your question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.  In addition, the present site has a significant 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research in the text of your question, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is arguably less strict.

Answer (score 1):

*Back up* most commonly means to walk or drive a vehicle backwards.

Metaphorically, in a conversation it means to return to a previously discussed point or topic.

Whether Zuckerberg was using it this way or with some other meaning in mind isn't clear from what you've said about his usage.